# Log files created at 5.30AM(IST(indain)) instead 12 AM IST. why?

Tags: java, logging, timezone, microservices

I have deployed java microservice web application in the sever(using K8's cluster), Based on TimeBasedTriggerringPolicy i am creating a new log file everyday, problem is files are created at 5.30Am instead of 12.00 am which causes some issue in my application. when i checked the server linux machine date and timezon format using commands everyting is normal IST(Indian format only), i checked in Master/worker machines. even though it is IST format still log files are creating at 5.30 Am. i don't understan where i am missing. or which machine i need to check for timezone. i am weak in this k8's deployment also. can anyone please help me on this? is it require to add timezone? or how this can be solved ? please need help

Comment: What time zone does your application actually use?

Comment: I did not mention any timezone in my application. i guess it is taking the default one

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen is it possible to add timezone to entire application by adding any single property? i have 15 microservices running for this application? is it require to add in all of them or how is it?

Comment: That might fail. Time to investigate.

Comment: Please use proper case in your writing here, “I” not “I”, “Is” not “is” when starting a sentence. This site is meant to be more like Wikipedia, not a casual chat room.

Comment: What is “k8's deployment”?

Comment: @basil just fix those things if they annoy you. You have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I'm trying to guide a new contributor.

Comment: @BasilBourque Sorry I am weak in English. apologies. I will try to improve myself next time while posting. Thank you

Comment: @basil k8 is most likely Kubernetes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JVM most likely does not understand the server locale setting if any and think the timezone is UTC.  You haven’t noticed because all time stamps look fine to you.

Investigate what locale you *should* be using and either set it explicitly in the K8 deployment environment  or in your code.

Comment: I found this in my master machine by typing locale command        
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE=C
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: I think I should change the locale as per Indian standard right?  like LC_CTYPE=en_IN.UTF-8  and  LC_TIME="en_IN.UTF-8"

Comment: No idea.  Your java code should end up having the correct localization for what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have added Time zone in deployment environment and started fixing the issues relating to it through code